# Use of Twig template for webform email

Tags: 8, theming, webforms, emails

I'm trying to help my father out by building a webform (D8 version) for the 4 theaters his Old Abbey Friends are putting up.

I've made the webform, now i'm setting up an email handler so that people get a confirmation email.  Straightforward enough, however, i'm getting lost when using the twig template option of that email handler on following items:

- how do i check if there's at least one checkbox checked in a checkbox element (containing 4 checkboxes)?
- how do i check which of the checkboxes is checked in the above element?
- how do i get the number in a number element that's part of a custom composite?  I tried using the data.composite_elementkey.elementkey syntax, but that just shows up blank.

Any feedback much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after a lot of searching and testing things out i've found the following things to work:

1. For the checkbox it won't work with the data.element_name syntax (or at least in any variation that tried, and that's a couple dozen).  What will work is this: `{{ webform_token('[webform_submission:values:ticketselectie]', webform_submission) }}`.  In this example "ticketselectie" is the name of the checkbox element with 4 checkboxes in it (options).  What you get from this is a string containing the option text for each checked checkbox, seperated by comma.

   2. You can use [the twig split filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/split.html) to extract an array out of checked checkboxes.
   3. Turns out you need to use data.custom_composite_element.0.element_key as the syntax.  given that a custom composite element only ever has one row, it's always the 0 delta you need, and then the name of the key behind that.  So given a custom composite with the name "abonnementen", and in there two number fields with the names "minderjarigen" and "anderen", that leaves with the following syntax: `data.abonnementen.0.anderen or data.abonnementen.0.minderjarigen`

That's it really.  Took way too long to find that, and it's kind of weird to me that the "data." syntax didn't work for the checkbox element.  So if anyone knows a better way, please do reply.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the elements documentations is a bit misleading. You can always try debugging like this:

```
{{ context|keys|join('+') }}
{{ data|keys|join('+') }}
{{ data|join('+') }}
```

which brought me to conditions like

```
{% if data.mycheckboxes %}

{% if mykey in data.mycheckboxes %}
```